# Making lists slide down when clicking on links

Tags: jquery, slidedown

what I want to achieve is pretty straightforward but for some reason I can't get it to work! What I want to do is When you click on one of the links to a specific genre I want the correspond list of song titles to display, preferably slide down. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my html so far:

```
<p><a class="rock" href="">ROCK</a> / <a class="blues" href="">BLUES</a></p>

                    <section class="container">
                    <div class="leftcolumn">
                        <ul class="rock">
                            <li>AUTOHAZE</li>
                            <li>BASSHOLES</li>
                            <li>BEAT ANGELS</li>
                            <li>BONFIRE MADIGAN </li>
                            <li>BOOM</li>       
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="blues">
                            <li>20 MILES    </li>
                            <li>AARON MOORE </li>
                            <li>ALBERT AMMONS   </li>
                            <li>ARON BURTON </li>
                            <li>ARTHUR CRUDUP   </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p><a class="rock" href="#">ROCK</a> / <a class="blues" href="#">BLUES</a></p>

                    <section class="container">
                    <div class="leftcolumn">
                        <ul class="rock" >
                            <li>AUTOHAZE</li>
                            <li>BASSHOLES</li>
                            <li>BEAT ANGELS</li>
                            <li>BONFIRE MADIGAN </li>
                            <li>BOOM</li>       
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="blues">
                            <li>20 MILES    </li>
                            <li>AARON MOORE </li>
                            <li>ALBERT AMMONS   </li>
                            <li>ARON BURTON </li>
                            <li>ARTHUR CRUDUP   </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </section>
```

Add following css:

```
ul {

    display:none;

}
```

the jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('a').bind('click',function () {
        var Class = $(this).attr('class');

        var ulName = 'ul.' + Class;
        var Display=$(ulName).css('display');
        var Dis = $(ulName).css('display');

        $(ulName).siblings().hide();
        if (Dis == "block" || Dis == "undefined") {
            $(ulName).slideUp();
        }
        else {
            $(ulName).slideDown().show(1);
        }

    })
});
```

**[DEMO IS HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jubair/7fHWT/3/)**

Comment: Hello jubair, this is great! Now if I wanted to have the link I clicked stay highlighted, would this work:  $(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('selected');

Comment: $(this).addClass('Selected');
$(this).siblings().removeClass('Selected');   this is working for me. If you want i can put it Fiddle

Comment: sure that would be great! I wasn't certain if that would work or not. Thank you Jubair : )

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help on this jubair! : )

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<p><a class="toggleBtn" data-id="rock" href="#">ROCK</a> / <a class="toggleBtn"
    data-id="blues" href="#">BLUES</a>
</p>
<section class="container">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <ul id="rock" class="toggleContainer">
            <li>AUTOHAZE</li>
            <li>BASSHOLES</li>
            <li>BEAT ANGELS</li>
            <li>BONFIRE MADIGAN</li>
            <li>BOOM</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="blues" class="toggleContainer">
            <li>20 MILES</li>
            <li>AARON MOORE</li>
            <li>ALBERT AMMONS</li>
            <li>ARON BURTON</li>
            <li>ARTHUR CRUDUP</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.toggleContainer {display:none;}
```

JQUERY

```
$(function () {
    $(".toggleBtn").click(function () {
        $(".toggleContainer").hide();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("data-id")).slideDown();
    });
});
```

[DEMO - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ACWsP/2/)

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you. This works great on Fiddle but for some reason it's not working at all when I incorporated it on my site. I can't figure out why.

Comment: In what way is it not working?  Did you include the CSS for toggleContainer?

Comment: Hi Michael, I got it to function properly. Thank you for your help : )

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><a class="rock" href="#">ROCK</a> / <a class="blues" href="#">BLUES</a></p>

                    <section class="container">
                    <div class="leftcolumn">
                        <ul class="rock" >
                            <li>AUTOHAZE</li>
                            <li>BASSHOLES</li>
                            <li>BEAT ANGELS</li>
                            <li>BONFIRE MADIGAN </li>
                            <li>BOOM</li>       
                        </ul>

                        <ul class="blues">
                            <li>20 MILES    </li>
                            <li>AARON MOORE </li>
                            <li>ALBERT AMMONS   </li>
                            <li>ARON BURTON </li>
                            <li>ARTHUR CRUDUP   </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    </section>
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var Class = $(this).attr('class');

        var ulName = 'ul.' + Class;
        $(ulName).hide();
        $(ulName).slideDown();
    });
});
```

I've tested it and work nice. **[Demo is here](http://jsfiddle.net/jubair/33AXr/1/)**

Comment: Hi jubair, i checked this out on fiddle but the list isn't hidden first?

Comment: Hi jubair, I think I might have it working but is there a way to make it toggle so that it shows the list then click again and hides it?

Comment: I am not clear... let me explain. First you want your container hidden and when clicked u just want to show the clicked item???

Comment: Yes, then if you click on it again I wanted it to hide the item

Comment: For example: if I clicked on the Rock link the list would slide down, then if I clicked on the Rock link again the list would then slide back up.

Comment: See the new post please :)